# Set button title from JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am looping through my `JSON` data and would like to set the button title accordingly to my `JSON` property title how should I do it ?

```
func getDataFromJSON(){
    //Calling getCollectionViewData from the RestParser class
    RestParser.sharedInstance.getConfig{json in
        //iterating to the JSON file to get alle data
        let results = json[0]["menu"]
        for (index: String,cofigData:JSON)in results{
          self.items.append(cofigData)
        }
        let testString = self.items[0]["title"]
        self.btnCollectionView.setTitle(testString.stringValue, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        println(testString.stringValue)
    }
}
```

This is what i try i the error that i receive is: `Can not subscript a value of tpye {['JSON]} sigh index of type string`

Comment: did you try to log `items["title"]`, I think it might be wrong type and cause error here?

Comment: @NghiaLuong well the problem is that it is obviously an array and key subscription..

Comment: Let's take a look for your JSON

Comment: @thedjnivek i updated my question i now can access the specific attribute but the button tittle does not change and the if i print out the value ( `            println(testString.stringValue)`) the value is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because `items` is obviously an array and key subscription `items["title"]` expects a dictionary.

Comment: sure that is clear .. but how to fix it is the question ;)

Comment: check the types. An array can only be subscripted by index, maybe `configData` is a dictionary which contains a key `title`. Something like this  `items[0]["title"]` but it considers only the first element of the array

Comment: `            let testString = self.items[0]["title"]
            self.btnCollectionView.setTitle(testString.stringValue, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            println(testString.stringValue)` that works but the button does not change the title

Comment: can the title of the button be set directly by a literal string? Try that before calling the parser function. Try also to dispatch the `setTitle` line to the main thread `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                  self.btnCollectionView.setTitle(testString.stringValue, forState: UIControlState.Normal)})
 `

Answer (score 0):

`items` is an `array`, you must convert it to `Dictionary`

Then, do this :

```
func getDataFromJSON(){
    //Calling getCollectionViewData from the RestParser class
    RestParser.sharedInstance.getConfig{ json in
        //iterating to the JSON file to get alle data
        let results = json[0]["menu"]
        for (index: String,cofigData:JSON)in results{
          self.items[index] = cofigData
        }
        let testString: String = items["title"]
        self.btnCollectionView.setTitle(testString, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

NB : Warning with `reference cycle` with self on your closure. I think you should add `[unowned self]` like this

```
RestParser.sharedInstance.getConfig{ [unowned self] json in
        //iterating to the JSON file to get alle data
```

> If the captured reference will never become nil, it should always be
>   captured as an unowned reference, rather than a weak reference.

Doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) about reference counting